# The shortest distance in the particle triangle

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, coulombs-law, protons

let's say: i have 3 particles, 2 of them are negatively charged electrons and the other are positively charged protons and i can arrange them in sequence like a triangle with 2 electrons at the base of the triangle and proton is at the top of the triangle.The distance between electron1 and proton is r1 and the distance between electron2 and proton is r2, the distance between two electrons r0 (as shown in the figure below):

[image]

With such an arrangement, the 2 electrons at the bottom will repel each other, but I assume that repulsion occurs only when the 2 electrons are at a certain distance. With the proton at the top of the triangle, it will. the interaction attracts the remaining two particles to its position. Two electrons will be attracted to points A and B lying on the distance between each electron and the other proton.Then the electrons will repel each other due to reaching a certain distance as I mentioned above (specifically, segment AB here. ).Electron1 is pushed to point C and electron2 is pushed to C' (both of these points are outside the original triangle).This process is repeated many times afterwards(as shown in the figure below):

[image]

So the question is, is it possible to determine the shortest distance between electrons and protons? And if so, please tell me how you determined it.Forgive me, if you feel that the image I drew myself is distorted and somewhat inaccurate, because I did not have a good ruler when I drew it. I would appreciate someone helping me to correct a few things. error in the question and also about the tags, thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  It's hard to tell.  Please edit your post to clarify the actual question you want an answer to.

Comment: sorry for this carelessness, i forgot to specify my question @MichaelSeifert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a theorem in Electrostatics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) that states that there does not exist a stable configuration of any number of point charges that interact purely electrostatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore quantum effects and restrict yourself to classical electrostatics, then I doubt that any configuration of two electrons and one proton will be stable. To confirm this you would have to work out the forces on each particle using [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) - I don't think you can approach a three-particle problem like this using diagrams alone.

In the real world of electrons and protons, where quantum effects cannot be ignored, what you have created is a hydrogen atom with an additional electron, known as a  [hydrogen anion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_anion) or hydride ion.